# Как реализовать счетчик секунд в libgdx.

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Поясню : Я пишу игру файтинг. 1 раунд  = 60 секунд.
Я так понимаю это работа с Time.Util. 
Как получить игровое время? а именно секунды?

Answer (score 0):

Инкрементируйте счетчик раз в секунду

```
    AtomicInteger ticker = new AtomicInteger(-1);
    Runnable runnableTask = () -> ticker.incrementAndGet();
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать `DeltaTime` и переменную для хранения, т.к. таймеры заведенные на определенное время не берут в расчет сворачивание приложения.

```
public roundTime=0;
public void startRound(){
    roundTime=60;
}
public boolean isEnded(float dt){
    roundTime-=dt;
    if(roundTime<=0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`startRound()` вызывать при начале раунда.
В `isEnded()` передавать значение `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`
(Естественно нужно еще доработать, но, думаю, вы справитесь)